# Curl - делаю parser на OLX. Перестал работать

Tags: php, парсер, curl, php-curl

```
function curl_content($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WinNT; en; rv:1.0.2) Gecko/20030311 Beonex/0.8.2-stable');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,false);
    $html=curl_exec($ch);
    return $html;
    unset($url);
}
```

Раньше этот код работал без проблем. Сейчас перестал. Ошибка на OLX:

> Что-то пошло не так :( Была зафиксированная подозрительная активность
>   с вашего IP-адреса.

Кстати, С десктопа работает. (Через OPENSERVER).
А через сервер перестал работать.
В чем может быть причина? Возможно что заблокировали? Или есть шанс оживить парсер?

Comment: Похоже вас забанили по айпи за слишком большое число запросов. Подождите сутки, попробуйте пару запросов. Если сработает - значит  был бан по айпи. Попробуйте с другого айпи

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh А у вас есть возможность проверить парсер со своего сервера?

Comment: echo curl_content('https://www.olx.ua/'); - все работает нормально

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh точно, заблокировали. А есть возможность через curl, обойти блокировку ip?

Comment: прокси или другой айпи на сервере. пока снова не забанят. надо подбирать безопасное число запросов, которые можно сделать без бана. например не более 100 в час.

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh у меня было 120 запросов и скрипт проработал около 2х месяцев

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102646/discussion-between-ivan-bolnikh-and-eduardrst).